# Can UI-Router ignore the initial state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to have UI-Router ignore the page state on initial page load and only kick in on subsequent state changes?

Basically, when a user navigates to `http://example.com/foo` for the first time, I will build the entire page on the server. Then when the user navigates to `/bar`, or later returns to `/foo`, I want Angular to handle the state change and inject the page contents into the view.

As it is now, UI-Router interprets the page-load as a state change and replaces the already-rendered contents, causing a flicker and wasting bandwidth. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can figure, this is how you can do it. Note that this simply hooks into the `$rootScope` event emitter and responds to events from the built-in `$locationProvider`, so your main module actually doesn't need to specify any extra dependencies (such as `ui.router`).

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var initialStateChangeCaptured = false;

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt) {
        if (initialStateChangeCaptured === false) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            initialStateChangeCaptured = true;
        }
    });
}])
```

If, for example, you wanted some pages to actually respond to the initial state change, You could add some state inspection by looking at `evt` or including `$stateProvider` and looking through it. But this handles my case pretty well.

I would be really happy if someone can point out anything missing from this method.